# Android - App icon not displayed for 2nd number of Phone Contact

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I have the below code snippet to add our app Icon to a phone Contact. It works fine when the phone contact has just one number. But in cases where there are two numbers assigned to a contact, the `app icon`(Application Icon) does not get displayed. The "results" array from below code returns a valid ID, indicating that a record was inserted, though the icon is not displayed. Please let me know what might be wrong. Appreciate your help.

```
    ContentResolver resolver = Utils.appContext.getContentResolver();
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, true))
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_NAME)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, ACCOUNT_TYPE)
            .build());

    ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
    builder.withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
    ops.add(builder.build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(Data.CONTENT_URI, true))
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, CONTACTS_MIME_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phoneNum)
            .build());

ContentProviderResult[] results = resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

Comment: app icon do u mean application icon ?

Comment: Yes correct, our application icon. It is displayed fine if the Contact has just one phone number

Answer (score 0):

I hope its Helps

From Example 
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/programatically-adding-contacts-with-photo-using-contacts-provider-in-android-example/

```
// to insert Photo in the table ContactsContract.Data
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO,stream.toByteArray())
                            .build());
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not working. It works for a Contact with a single phone number